# How can I have multiple functions in onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing code to be able to search multiple fields within cards that pull customer data from endpoints. The first function that searches customerID works fine, but I would also like to be able to search the other fields. But I am having trouble getting it recognize multiple fields.

How can I register multiple functions inside an onkeyup field and if I am selecting the forename field in querySelector properly?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
    <div class="form-outline" id="customer-search-bar">
        <input type="search" id="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer ID" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="searchID() && searchForename();" >
    </div>
    <div class="card-lists" id="card-lists">
       <div class="row">
          {% for data in raw.CustomerDataEntries %}
          <div class="card col-sm-12 mb-3" id="card-perim">
             <div class="card-body" id="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Customer ID: {{ data.ExternalId }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title" name="forename">Forename: {{ data.Fields.forename }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Surname: {{ data.Fields.surname }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Postcode: {{ data.Fields.post_code }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Matches: {{ data.Matches }}</h5>
                <a href="#" class="tableButton">Details</a>
                <a href="#" class="tableButton">Edit</a>
             </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function searchID() {
    const input = document.getElementById('filter').value.toUpperCase();

    const cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-lists');
    console.log(cardContainer);

    const cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName('card-body');
    console.log(cards);

    for (let i = 0; 0 < cards.length; i++){
        let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5.card-title");
        if(title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
            cards[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            cards[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function searchForename() {
    const input = document.getElementById('filter').value.toUpperCase();

    const cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-lists');
    console.log(cardContainer);

    const cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName('card-body');
    console.log(cards);

    for (let i = 0; 0 < cards.length; i++){
        let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5[name='forename']");
        if(title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
            cards[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            cards[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value within the `onkeyup` attribute follows JS syntax, so you should separate the statements with a semi-colon, `;`.

```html
<input type="search" id="filter" onkeyup="searchID(); searchForename();" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer ID" aria-label="Search" />
```

*However* using inline event handlers is not good practice. Modern best practice is to unobtrusively bind your event handlers. In native JS you can achieve this by using `addEventListener()`, like this:

```js
let filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
filter.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  searchID();
  searchForename();
});

function searchID() {
  console.log('searchID');
}

function searchForename() {
  console.log('searchForename');
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer ID" aria-label="Search" />
```

---

> The second function searchForename() still doesn't work for me though

The main reason it doesn't work is partly because it's a duplication of the work being done in `searchId()`, so anything displayed by `searchId()` will be hidden in `searchForname()`.

In addition, because you set `display` state for every `.card-item` in the card. This means that if the last item does not contain the searched text the entire card is hidden - even if a previous card *did* contain the text.  To fix this hide the card to start with, then display it only if a match is found.

Here's a working example with the search logic corrected - note that I commented out `searchForename()` in the `keyup` handler as it works on a subset of the same
elements as `searchID`, so its use there is redundant.

```js
let filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
filter.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  searchID();
  //searchForename();
});

function searchID() {
  const input = filter.value.toUpperCase();
  const cardContainer = document.querySelector('#card-lists');
  const cards = cardContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-body');

  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.style.display = 'none';
    card.querySelectorAll(".card-body h5.card-title").forEach(title => {
      if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        card.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  });
}

function searchForename() {
  const input = filter.value.toUpperCase();
  const cardContainer = document.querySelector('#card-lists');
  const cards = cardContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-body');

  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.style.display = 'none';
    card.querySelectorAll(".card-body h5.card-title.forename").forEach(title => {
      if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        card.style.display = "block";
      } 
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="form-outline" id="customer-search-bar">
    <input type="search" id="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer ID" aria-label="Search" />
  </div>
  <div class="card-lists" id="card-lists">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Customer ID: 123</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title forename">Forename: Lorem</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Surname: Ipsum</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Postcode: 90210</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Matches: Foobar</h5>
          <a href="#" class="tableButton">Details</a>
          <a href="#" class="tableButton">Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Customer ID: 123</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title forename">Forename: Dolor</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Surname: Sit</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Postcode: 92893</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title">Matches: Fizzbuzz</h5>
          <a href="#" class="tableButton">Details</a>
          <a href="#" class="tableButton">Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
My JS code:
```

One last thing - note that I removed the `id` attributes in the content you create in the loop. This is because repeated `id` are invalid, they must contain unique values within the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I have made the changes to fit best practice. The second function searchForename() still doesn't work for me though. Do you think it's because of the way I used the querySelector to pick the field? Is there a best practice way to select multiple fields in querySelector?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with an explanation of the issue and a fix for you